# How do I to get a full screen background video hero?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a site I am working on and I want it to load to a full background video with the title over it. However, I also want to the user to beable to scroll to other full screen sections of a page. How do I get this to work.

Here is a Codepen link
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rskjF

The about div is the next section I want to make. It is supposed to be(well every section is) 100% height and width. It seems from the look of some sites, you can achieve this with clever positioning.

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to this - http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/09/18/onepagescroll-js-creating-an-apples-iphone-5s-website/

Comment: @rubo123 yes, but with a video that has no controls, like this http://www.degordian.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've used Syd Lawrence's [jquery.videoBG](http://github.com/sydlawrence/jquery.videoBG) with good success. Just use [this example](http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/demo_div.html) to make your hero div have a video background. Then write the rest of your page below that div.

(Bonus tip: If you don't already know about using 'vh' and 'vw' as CSS units you may want to look into them. Example:`.row{height: 100vh;}`)